# Storing multiple key value pairs SecKeyChain

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, keychain

Application requires me to store multiple sensitive data in terms of Key value pair in KeyChain iOS.When i used SecKeyChain in Xamarin it just stores only one key value pair.

How could i store many key value pairs in Keychain-ios,Xamarin-iOS.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to store a dictionary as the value that's stored, and then write a glue method that adds/removes keys to that single key/value pair.

I don't know if there is a better way or not, but this worked.